# birthday probability program in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, birthday-paradox

I have been given an assignment to create a Fortran 90 program that calculates how many people are needed so that the probability of two or more people having the same birthday becomes 90%.

I would like to define variables as follows:

- P2 = probability of having at least 2 people of the same birthday among n people
- P1 = probability that all n people have different birthdays
- P2= 1- P1
- P1 = (364/365)*(363/365)*(362/365).... ((365-n-1)/365)

Edited: This is the code I have tried to compose:

```
program birth1
  implicit none
  integer:: n
  real(8):: P1, P2

n=1
P1 = 1

     do
        p1 = P1 * ((365.0d0 -n +1)/365.0d0)

        If (P1 <= 0.1) exit

         n= n+1
   end do

  write (*,*) n
  stop
  end program birth1
```

This code has worked and I got 41 as the output. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a homework problem for a stats class.  Just a few comments.  1) The `8` in `real(8)` is non-portable.  There are portable ways to find the kind type parameter.  Try `integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)` after `implicit none` and use  `real(dp)`.  2) Your do-loop is infinite and the variable `n` is never set to a value. 3)  You set `p1` to 0.9, but overwrite that value in the do-loop where it seems you want to accumulate the product of probabilities. 4) It is okay to use whitespace to enhance the readability of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. May I know how to make codes for inverse probability problem? For example, I have the value of P2 = 0.9. I would like to find for what value of n I would get P2= 0.9 (given that the formula for P2 is stated)

Comment: I think you're getting closer to what you need.  Ask yourself what if I have `n = 1`  people.  Your `p1` should be `p1 = 1`.  What if I have `n = 2`, then `p1 = p1 * (365 - n + 1) / 365.d0` where you are using the previous value of `p1` from the `n = 1` step.  Now, what if `n = 3`, you have `p1 = p1 * (365 - n + 1) / 365.d0` where `p1` is the value from the`n = 2` step.  This should get you started on the need loop structure.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed all variables to real and also changed the loop formula. Now, my question is, do I have to put a range of "do", for example, "do n = 1,365"? Also, how can I command to find the value of "n" for a given value of P1 or P2?

Comment: I have added exit statement, but now, the output becomes a negative number, edited on my question. May I know what went wrong?

Comment: You should move the initial `p1=1` to before the `do` loop. With the loop, you presumably try to iteratively calculate `n` without ever setting a value for it. How about setting `n=1` outside the loop, and then increasing it by one after calculating `p1` in the loop. Also, you may want to change your test condition from `==` to `<=`.

Comment: I did that now, but still I am not getting any output.

Comment: You've added and unnecessary `do` loop now. Only one is required, the one in which `p1` is calculated based on the current estimate for `n`, if `p1` is below some threshold, you exit the loop, otherwise you increase `n` and the loop repeats.